# How to delete an element of an array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
CustomItemCollection.find({name: urlPath}, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
        let returnedData = data[0].item;
        for(var i = 0; i < returnedData.length; i++){
          if(returnedData[i]._id === checkboxButton){
            //delete this object nested inside the array
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

Im trying to delete an element inside an array. I tried following some other posts on here but they didn't work. Can someone tell me how to do this? Here's the schema if that'll help:

```
const CustomItemSchema = {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 1,
    unique: 1
  },
  item: [{
    myItems: String
  }]
}
```

i wanna delete one of the "myItems" created using its id. I have gotten its id but i don't know how to delete it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you only need to use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) like this:

```
CustomItemCollection.updateOne(
{
  "name": urlPath
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "item": {
      "_id": checkboxButton
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QY3SZ_4o1eB)

Note that I've used `updateOne` but you can use [other query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) as `findOneAndUpdate` or `updateMany` if you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome. Also if the issue has been solved, mark the answer as accepted is appreciated.